# Woocommerce, prevent login after registration and redirect to custom URL

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, logout

I'm looking for a way to prevent the automatic login after registration (i.e. by logging him out after registration) **and** redirect him to a custom URL.
So far I'm only able to do both of them individually, but the combination of it is not working.
For redirect after registration I'm using the following:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'custom_redirection_after_registration', 10, 1 );
    function custom_redirection_after_registration( $redirection_url ){
        // Change the redirection Url
        $redirection_url = "https://...";
        return $redirection_url; 
    }
```

When including the wp_logout() function within the function above, I think that the redirect after logout is being triggered. If that assumption is correct, I unfortunately don't know how I can redirect only that logout that's being triggered directly after the registration.

I hope that anyone can help me out? It's greatly appreciated!
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever has also the same question as I had:
This is how I got it to work:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'custom_redirection_after_registration', 1);

function custom_redirection_after_registration( $redirection_url ){
    // Change the redirection Url
    add_action('wp_logout','only_redirect_unverfied_users_after_registration',1);
    wp_logout();
    wp_destroy_current_session();
    $redirection_url = "https://...";
    return $redirection_url;
}



function only_redirect_unverfied_users_after_registration(){
    $redirection_url = "https://";
    wp_redirect( $redirection_url);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, It may helpful.

```
function wc_custom_registration_redirect() {
    wp_logout();
    wp_destroy_current_session();
    return home_url('/');
}
add_action('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'wc_custom_registration_redirect', 99);
```